# How to fix Error: Cannot find module 'archiver' error while creating a blank ionic app?

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I have installed node, npm, ionic and cordova by following this tutorial : http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html

Now when I create a blank app using the command

```
ionic start todo blank
```

I get the following error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'archiver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/lib/utils.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Did a lot of googling but couldn't figure out the solution.
Kindly help me resolve this.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry if sounds stupid, but did you do an `npm install` in the directory where you package.json is? if not try it first. It might simply be that you haven't installed all you npm dependencies.

Comment: Thank you, i had the same, yes, didn't do an 'npm install' :D

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This problem comes when installing without sudo, In that case we need to add modules like archiver and others one by one. I would recommend re-installing via sudo to avoid all this.